# WebView.onPause() for API level 10

Tags: android, video, webview, youtube, fragment

I am currently opening a youtube channel inside a WebView.
It loads all fine and i can play the channels videos with no problem.
But when i navigate back, and the Fragment containing the WebView gets removed, the audio keeps playing.

To prevent this, i am calling the *WebViews onPause()* in the *Fragments onPause()* like this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webView.onPause();
}
```

This works like a charm.
But my problem is that *WebView.onPause()* is **only for API 11** and above. But my app has to be **minimum API 10** ...
So my question is: How can i stop the audio playing on all API levels ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have one WebView in the Fragment, use the following code to pause **ALL** WebViews in the Fragment:

```
// In the Fragment's onPause
@Override
public void onPause(){

    super.onPause();

    // Check if WebView is null first since onPause can occasionally get called before all your views are initialized
    if(mWebView != null) {

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){

            mWebView.onPause(); // Normal onPause for versions greater than or equal to API 11

        }

        mWebView.pauseTimers(); // This does the same thing as onPause but does it for all the WebViews, it works on all API levels
    }

}
```

Let me know if it works for you. It should, but the WebView can be finicky and doesn't always behave the way you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change

```
webView.onPause
```

to:

```
this.callHiddenWebViewMethod("onPause");
```

Comment: Is this a custom function? Because i cant call it on Activity, Fragment or WebView.

Comment: is this custom?